# check if checkbox is checked and call intent in onclick

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android, i have two checkboxes in my code along with a button. when the button is clicked, it should show a toast which is working fine but when the checkbox1 is checked , then the button should call another intent along with showing toast (disable bluetooth) and when checkbox2 is also checked, the button should call another intent when clicked (like showing another toast) i. other words, if both the checkboxes are checked, the button click should call three intents when clicked, hope that is clear.

```
  public void btd(View view) { 
    BluetoothAdapter blue = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        blue.disable();
} (this is not required though, toast will also work)


package com.example.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    CheckBox checkBox_one = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_two = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_three = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_four = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_five = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // SAVE CHECKBOX STATE//

        checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
        Log.i("start", "" + isChecked);
        checkBox_one.setChecked(isChecked);
        checkBox_one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("boolean", "" + isChecked);
                MainActivity.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,
                        "isChecked");
            }
        });

        checkBox_two = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        boolean isCheckedTwo = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedTwo");
        checkBox_two.setChecked(isCheckedTwo);
        checkBox_two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

                MainActivity.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,
                        "isCheckedTwo");
            }
        });
    }

    public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
                .getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
                .getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return isChecked;

    }

    // -------------------------//

    public void optimize(View view) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Toast",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

i have tried this but it's not complete

```
if (checkBox_one.isChecked() && checkBox_two.isChecked()) {
            //do something
         } else if (checkBox_one.isChecked()) {
            //do something
         } else if (checkBox_two.isChecked()) {         
            //do something
```

Comment: Im not sure if i get you right but I think in your optimize try do smoething like `if(checkbox_one.isChecked && checkbox_tow.isChecked){Then do something}`

Comment: so what's wrong with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

in this case do not use else if, because as soon as 1 statement matches the condition (result is true) the other else-if will not be tested

so use separated if statements for each case.

```
onClick(View v){

showToast(...);

if(chkButton1.isChecked){
//fo work for chk1
}

if(chkButton2.isChecked){
//fo work for chk2
}

}
```

http://www.visionsdeveloper.com/tutorial/java/java-decision-making.jsp

> The if statement executed from top to down. As soon as one of the
>   condition is true, statement associated with that if statement
>   executed.   If none of the condition is true than else statement will
>   be executed, **only one of the statement executed from list of else if statements**.